# Precision Issue with Log

Tags: precision-and-accuracy, machine-precision

I have the following codes. Naturally, I expect to get zero. I thought it is due to some possible issues stated as "Machine-precision inputs can give numerically wrong answers on branch cuts:".

```
In[526]:= w0 /. iNputIsoDaMax3Ethanol

Out[526]= 1.19498

In[528]:= fool[q_?NumericQ, p_?NumericQ] := Log[q/p]

In[529]:= fool[w0, w0] /. iNputIsoDaMax3Ethanol

Out[529]= -1.11022*10^-16
```

How can I code so that it gives 0 when the inputs are same within some precision.

Thank you.

Comment: How about Chop?

Comment: With version 11.2 on a Mac, I get `0.` Try removing `?NumericQ` from definition of `fool`, i.e., `fool[q_, p_] := Log[q/p]` Since 'fool` does not use numeric techniques, there is no reason to restrict its arguments. Otherwise do as @bills suggests.

Comment: It is difficult to replicate an issue without the full code.

Comment: Sorry, iNputIsoDaMax3Ethanol is an output from the NonLinearFit. It involves loading data, using thermodynamic properties from CoolProp. So, it will be lengthy and required CoolProp.dll to run. I guess, we can give any machine precision output to the function. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There should be better results with the following definition

```
dodo[q_?NumericQ, p_?NumericQ] := Log[Divide[q, p]]
```

The reason is that `q/p` is actually interpreted as `Times[q, 1/p]`.

For example,

```
w = 1.647183210553395;
fool[w, w]

(* -1.1102230246251565*^-16 *)

dodo[w, w]

(* 0. *)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It works.